# How do the singularity breaches works in The Flash?

Tags: plot-explanation, arrowverse, the-flash

I just saw all 5 currently released episodes of Season 2 from *The Flash* and got a few questions. Answers to any of my questions will be helpful, some questions might not have been explained but if I missed some parts and if they answer my questions then please help me.

We have seen the singularity brought Jay Garrick to this Earth without his powers, so

1. How is Zoom able to come to Barry's Earth with power?
2. If any channel exists between the two Earths, then why is only one way travel shown?
3. How does Zoom know about the speedster on Earth-One (Barry's world)?
4. How did Earth-Two's Harrison know about Mercury Labs and why does he steal an unknown device?
5. If Zoom is so powerful then why is he sending meta-humans to kill Flash rather than coming himself?

Comment: I haven't seen season 2 yet, but please make sure that all those various questions are sufficiently related to each other (possibly by rewording or putting them into structure under an all-encompassing major question), to justify putting them into a single question. If they aren't, you should rather ask them as individual questions to make them answerable and assessable/acceptable individually.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there are more then one question and they should be separately asked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> We have seen the singularity brought Jay Garrick to this Earth without his powers

No we haven't. Nothing about the singularity was stated to take powers away. We later hear Jay say Zoom took his powers, which he later admitted was a lie, and that he lost his powers due to using a speed enhancing formula similar to Velocity-6.

> How is Dr. Zoom able to come to Barry's earth with power?

See above. Also, just "Zoom", not called Dr. Zoom in the show.

> If any channel exists between the two earths, then why is only one way travel shown?

The main singularity allowed two way travel. Zoom is obviously returning to Earth 2 as well. The scoobies had to stabilize the singularity in Star Labs to allow travel to Earth 2 using the Speed Cannon, so the same needs to be done on that end, for normal people.

They sent Grood and the Trickster's Bombs via the Speed Cannon. Zoom can jump through breeches without issue and without a Speed Cannon, likely due to his faster speed, unlike Barry.

> How does Dr. Zoom know about this speedster on earth-one (Barry's world)?

Not explained yet. Tune in next week(s). Likely he did the same as Jay and Wells-2, and did surveillance/research. Or picked up a newspaper. Most likely, he used Earth-2 Cisco, the villainous Reverb, to find out.

> How did Harry (earth-two) know about Mercury Labs and why does he steal an unknown device?

Not explained yet. Tune in next week(s). Likely, Mercury Labs exists on Earth-2.

> If Doctor Zoom is so powerful then why is he sending meta-humans to kill Flash rather than coming himself?

Explained in the Christmas episode:
Zoom wants to fatten Barry up like a Speed-Force Turkey before taking his power.

Answer (score 1):

This question is hard and the only answer I can think of (this answer is my theory) is that Jay was hit with something that made him lose his powers. So, this will be unlikely to happen to anyone else.

One way travel is show only too the main characters. When the original singularity took place the probably would have been tons of stuff that went to earth two.

Well this could be a major idea for the season. One idea is time travel to when they have already started fighting.

Mercury labs of earth two. The weapon wouldn't have been unknown as he and the owner if Mercury labs would have got along.

We will find out. Caitlyn will probably  ask the question herself sometime next episode.

Answer (score 1):

I'm fairly certain that in the last episode (11/3/15) Jay said that his powers were taken by Zoom. He tells Barry that he could die fighting Zoom or worse, lose his powers.

As far as point 4 goes, I'd be willing to bet there is a Mercury Labs on Earth 2.